# Ionic 3. Unexpected token <

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

i've recently updated ionic to version 3.9.2 but an error occur when run "ionic cordova run android --device" or when i use Ionic DevApp.

When i execute the command on my smartphone Huawaei with android 7.0 all work perfectly, but i obtain error when run on my tablet samsung with android 4.4.4

Running "ionic doctor check" no issues detected.

The error is "Unexpected token <", no other details.

This is my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/email-composer": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/onesignal": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/twitter-connect": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "android-versions": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.1",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^1.6.1",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-email-composer": "^0.8.11",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.14",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.0.4",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "onesignal-cordova-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "twitter-connect-plugin": "git+https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin.git",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^4.0.5",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "onesignal-cordova-plugin": {},
      "twitter-connect-plugin": {
        "FABRIC_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "TWITTER_KEY": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
        "TWITTER_SECRET": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-email-composer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "APP_NAME": "xxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "xxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
```

This is my system info

```
Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.0
Angular Core: 5.0.0
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.0.0
Node: 6.11.4
OS Platform: macOS Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
```

This is my config.xml

```
<widget id="XXXXX" version="14.0.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>xxxxxxx</name>
    <description>xxxxx</description>
    <author email="xxxxxxx" href="xxxxxxxxxxxx">xxxxxxxxx</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="deployment-target" value="7.0" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.6:8100" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.14" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" spec="^4.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="^1.6.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.0.4" />
    <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="twitter-connect-plugin" spec="git+https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin.git">
        <variable name="FABRIC_KEY" value="xxxxxxxxx" />
        <variable name="TWITTER_KEY" value="xxxxxxxx" />
        <variable name="TWITTER_SECRET" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="^0.8.11" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^1.9.1">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="^5.1.1">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

If i inspect my tablet device in console i see that error refer to a row in main.js This is the row

```
MyApp = __decorate([
        Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__angular_core__["m" /* Component */])({template:/*ion-inline-start:"/path/src/app/app.html"*/`<ion-menu [content]="content" persistent>\n\n  <ion-content padding-top class="menu-content">\n\n    <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle float-left clear color="white">\n      <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>\n    </button>\n    <div class="imglogo" text-center no-padding>\n      <img src="assets/img/icona-app-210gr.png">\n    </div>\n    <ion-list class="menulist" no-lines inset>\n      <button ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)" detail-none text-center>\n        <strong class="bebas" translate>{{p.title}}</strong>\n      </button>\n\n      <button ion-item (click)="flagTapped(\'it\')" detail-none text-center>\n        <strong class="bebas" translate>{{\'LANG_ITALIAN\'}}</strong>\n      </button>\n      <button ion-item (click)="flagTapped(\'en\')" detail-none text-center>\n        <strong class="bebas" translate>{{\'LANG_ENGLISH\'}}</strong>\n      </button>\n\n      <a ion-item href="xxxxxxxxxxxx" detail-none text-center>\n        <strong class="bebas" translate>{{\'LANG_PRIVACY\'}}</strong>\n      </a>\n    </ion-list>\n    <button ion-button menuToggle clear color="white" float-right icon-end (click)="logout()">\n        <span translate>{{\'LANG_LOGOUT\'}}</span>\n      <ion-icon name="log-out"></ion-icon>\n    </button>\n  </ion-content>\n\n</ion-menu>\n\n<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>\n`/*ion-inline-end:"/path/src/app/app.html"*/
        })
```

I don't understend the error. In phone all is ok, ma in tablet no. It's a Ionic bug or a my error?

Thank you

**UPDATE 13/11/2017**
New investigation: the problem is on device with android version <= 4.4.4 either smartphone and tablet.
But Ionic 3 does not natively support android 4.4+?

**UPDATE 13/11/2017 #2**
Problem solved. I've installed crosswalk plugin and not all work

Comment: What Ionic version were you upgrading from?

Comment: I come from version 3.8.0 but i've follow guide to update by ionic changelog

Answer (score 0):

> When i execute the command on my smartphone Huawaei with android 7.0
>   all work perfectly, but i obtain error when run on my tablet samsung
>   with android 4.4.4
>
> The error is "Unexpected token <", no other details.

I've just had a very similar issue, caused by the fact that on one particular device (coincidentially Android 4.4.4), the browser webview was simply too old to understand the compiled JavaScript.

This will result in the dreaded "white screen of death", and can be particularly painful to debug.

A simple solution is to just use crosswalk:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Rebuild and the issue should be gone.

While this will bloat your APK, adding some extra 25Mb, I'd advise to always use crosswalk when supporting rather old devices.

Even if it does work without on these, often times a few subtle things like animated inputs and such will be broken, making for a bad user experience.

Comment: Crosswalk isn't maintained anymore. The strange thing is that in ionic 3.8.0 I had no problems

Comment: @NicolaCampaniolo True, then again the Ionic [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/browser-support/) still lists it as an option. I'd agree that it is a stop-gap measure at best, though.

Answer (score 0):

android 7.0 supports es6 (es2015) and android 4.4.4 probably doesn't - I had a somewhat similar problem because autocomplete mistakenly imported one of classes from ionic-angular es2015

I had import { Slides } from '**ionic-angular/es2015**' instead of import { Slides } from '**ionic-angular**';

Answer (score 0):

**Check that the bundle file really exists.**
Usually this problem happens because the browser cannot find the bundle JS file. This "<" token is no more than the html opening tag of a 404 response server. **App program expects to read JS not HTML**